# Is there a way to create a variable in JAVA that stores a arraylist and each element in the arraylist has its own list? name of elements given by user

Tags: java, string, variables, arraylist

[Image of variable hierarchy (Please Check)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mfev.jpg)

I want this specific variable to be a list of usernames, and each of these users will have some bookings... I tried adding an arraylist within an arraylist but that doesnt allow the user to name the usernames, they have to be predefined, please give me a method to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store any kind of object in an `ArrayList`.

You could define your own class `Booking` that contains information about a booking:

```
public class Booking {
    // ... whatever information is necessary for a booking
}
```

And then define a class `User` that contains information about a user, including a list of bookings:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Booking> getBookings() {
        return bookings;
    }

    // ... other methods as necessary
}
```

And then you can make an `ArrayList` of `User` objects, where each `User` object contains a list of `Booking` objects:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```